# PHP strpos() of "\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n" characters

Tags: php, str-replace, strpos

I have a text in MySQL database that is requested in "$description" and I would like to know if `\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n` is present in the description. So i got:

```
if(strpos($description, "\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n") !== FALSE) {
echo "String is here.";
} else {
echo "String not found.";
}
```

but this always outputs "String not found." and I believe there is a bad escaping in the searched string (`\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n`). How can I strpos by `\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n` ? Also, I would probably end up str_replace-ing every `\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n` with `\r\n` as somebody made some bad escaping functions and data arrived as `\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n` instead of `\r\n`, so a str_replace faces the same problem also. I could use help on any of these tasks (str_pos,str_replace).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Seems that stackoverflow cut some "\"s where not in code tags. Code in tags is the desired string.

Comment: Enlighten me, will you ?

Comment: @Manny use backticks `\`\`` to enter raw text.

Comment: There's really no enlightenment to be had. It's just better to not generate such strings in the first place, and certainly not *have your language force their creation for you*.

Comment: @Ignacio it's not PHP. it's some programmer using it. Feel the difference

Comment: A method to avoid the string escaping issues of PHP is to put the desired search string in a raw text file. Then use `$subject = trim(file_get_contents("exact.txt"))` to have it contain the value as seen in the text editor.

Comment: I did not produce this `\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n` . I just assumed it was bad escaping. I am supposed to fix this on current entered data but don't want to replace in mysql, I want to replace on display. So I would like to replace `\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n` with `\r\n` in `$description` . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the unfortunate nature of the detecting the backslash character is because it is also the universal escaping character.  And to put a literal backslash into a string, you have to escape it - with itself

That is to say, if you wanted to detect a *single* backslash, your code might look like this

```
if(strpos($description, '\\' ) !== FALSE)
```

Therefore, if you want to detect eight, consecutive backslashes, your string to match against will need double-that - sixteen.

```
if(strpos($description, '\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\' ) !== FALSE)
```

Therefore, your final match using `strpos()` would have to look like this

```
if(strpos($description, '\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n' ) !== FALSE)
```

Also noticed that I switched to single-quotes.  That's because `\n` and `\r` [are interpreted](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) inside of double-quoted string literals.

You can also do this with regular expressions, which is going to be a bit more flexible and powerful

```
if ( preg_match( "/\\x5C{8}[rn]/", $description ) )
```

### EDIT

For search-replacing, I suggest something like this.  As I mentioned above, the regular expression is going to be more powerful - this one will match `\r` or `\n` (and not just when they're adjacent) with ANY quantity of preceding backslashes, not only 8 of them.

```
$description = preg_replace( "/\\x5C+([rn])/", '\\\${1}', $description );
```

Comment: If the number of backslashes is even, then `print '\\\\n'` is identical to `print "\\\\n"` - the tokenizer treats double quoted strings not worse than single quoted.

Comment: @mario - yes, that is true.  I still think it's more pragmatic to use single-quotes for such things.

Comment: @Manny I added a search/replace suggestion as well.

Comment: \n shouldn't be replaced with literal \n I believe.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strpos($description, '\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n') !== FALSE) {
echo "String is here.";
} else {
echo "String not found.";
}
```

[further reading](http://php.net/types.string)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$in = "abc";
if(preg_match('/\n|\r/',$in)){
    echo 'found';
}else{
    echo 'not found';
}
```